# Using different aws credentials in Bitbucket pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, amazon-eks, bitbucket-pipelines

I've a bitbucket pipeline that must have multiple aws credentials for different duties.

In the first lines, I have custom ECR image. To pull it, I created an AWS user for only ECR read only permissions. access-key and secret-key parameters are the keys of that user.

And in this ECR image, I embedded another AWS user's credentials to do the rest of the work (image push etc). But somehow, the credentials that I used for pulling base image running in steps too. Because of this situation, image push is being denied.

I tried to use **export AWS_PROFILE=deployment** but it doesn't help.

Is the credentials for base image pull being applied pipeline-wide?

And how can I overcome with this situation?

Thank you.

```
image: 
name: <ECR Image>
  aws:  
    access-key: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
    secret-key: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

pipelines:   
  - step: 
      name: "Image Build & Push" 
      services: 
        -docker 
        script: 
         - export AWS_PROFILE=deployment
         - export ENVIRONMENT=beta 
         - echo "Environment is ${ENVIRONMENT}" 
         - export DOCKER_IMAGE_BUILDER="${BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG}:builder" 
         - make clean 
         - make build BUILD_VER=${BITBUCKET_TAG}.${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER} \  APP_NAME=${BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG} \ 
    DOCKER_IMAGE_BUILDER=${DOCKER_IMAGE_BUILDER} 
         - make test
         - docker tag ....
         - docker push .....
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do here instead of baking credentials inside the images:

Use one credential for pulling/pushing/taggin the image, why not use the same for pushing the image.

If that is something you don't wanna do:

Create an IAM role and give that permission to tag/push the images and assume this role from the earlier credentials being exported, No need to bake credentials in the images.

I found the following example in the [documentation](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/aws-ecr-push-image/src/master/README.md)

```
    script:

    # build the image
    - docker build -t my-docker-image .

    # use the pipe to push to AWS ECR
    - pipe: atlassian/aws-ecr-push-image:1.2.2
        variables:
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
        AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
        IMAGE_NAME: my-docker-image
        TAGS: '${BITBUCKET_TAG} latest'G
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, let me explain my situation a little more, we have lots of repos inside a bitbucket project. And unfortunately Bitbucket doesn't have project level variables to control AWS Creds from there. Writing creds to each projects is long and ineffective process. Because of we are using same account with other teams, workspace level credentials should not be used either. And also, using ECR base image is requiring creds and I'm planning to write them to workspace level, so all projects can use it. It should be read only. Is there a way to overwrite creds in this matter?

Comment: and the profile you mentioned in the question has correct credentials, in that case, you just need to authenticate(missing in the shared config) and tag appropriately. [here](https://gist.github.com/toddlers/3f3a1b54254cdf07165d1bd1ba6bc47e) have a working config, which I use for my own pipeline.

Comment: Hi again, what do you mean by shared config? Yes I tried it as I mention before, but it didn't work unfortunately. my export AWS_PROFILE=deployment comment doesn't affect.

Comment: if the profile didn't work, then try exporting them directly as in the example I've shown, plus hook in [get-caller-identity](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sts/get-caller-identity.html) cli command as well, to check which credentials are being used.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenID Connect is nice feature https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/deploy-on-aws-using-bitbucket-pipelines-openid-connect/